# Windows 2016 - why does one instance open cmd as admin and another not, both are admin login?

Tags: windows, windows-server

Given:
2 instances of Windows 2016 Server

Why is it on one instance I can open c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe and it opens as Administrator. However, on my other instance it does not.

I am logged in to both instances as an Administrator.

[image]

[image]

Comment: look at the properties of the file. you can tell a file to always execute as admin, so if someone modified the file properties on one server but not the other, that would explain your issue.

Comment: The one on the left is modifying a shortcut properties ...

Comment: When you open command line as admin via the Power menu (Windows-X) on both instances, you get two different results too? I have to admit I never delve into the bowels of my C drive to launch a CLI, I always do it via Windows-X, and it always opens as admin if I so choose.

Comment: Are these bultin Administrator accounts on both servers?